# mac os x crashing overnight

Tags: mac

It seems every day or close to it, my MacBook Air crashes. I'm running the very latest MacOS Monterey 12.2.1 with these specs:

MacBook Air (Retina, 13-inch, 2018), 1.6 GHz Dual-Core Intel Core i5

I can't find anything from /var/log/system.log

```
Feb 14 05:34:15 Jasons-MacBook-Air syslogd[112]: ASL Sender Statistics
Feb 14 05:47:53 Jasons-MacBook-Air syslogd[112]: ASL Sender Statistics
Feb 14 06:01:28 Jasons-MacBook-Air syslogd[112]: ASL Sender Statistics
Feb 14 10:41:48 localhost bootlog[0]: BOOT_TIME 1644835308 159606
Feb 14 10:41:52 localhost syslogd[112]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.cdscheduler" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
Feb 14 10:41:52 localhost syslogd[112]: Configuration Notice:
        ASL Module "com.apple.install" claims selected messages.
        Those messages may not appear in standard system log files or in the ASL database.
```

Comment: Have you tried looking for panic logs? If you have them, they'd be helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Suffering from the same issue as OP, im running MacOS Mac-Mini 12.2.1 and while 12.2 was worse, 12.2.1 only started crashing in the last week.

The following i've done and noticed:

- changed syslog service to log (udp! (important to catch any errors without packet negotiation)) to a remote source.
- Ansible to collect facts every day at 7.

According to ansible this morning the uptime was 5 hours. So the logfiles around 2am showed a lot of errors on the softwareupdated (which also seems to have woken up my system).

Hope this helps a little and happy hunting.

edit: one day later, disabling the softwareupdate check seems to have done the trick.